# trust between two different forests

Tags: active-directory

I have 2 domains -  adatum.com and  contoso.com what I want to do is to allow users from one domain remote to connect to another domain

I've created a two way trust between these 2  domains but I can't give necessary rights to either domain. When i go to the remote desktop tab to assign rights I can see both domains but it seems like I can't select or find groups or users from the other domain and via versa

anyone have any suggestion? what exactly should i look?

Comment: Have you opened the required ports on each domain controller? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179442

Comment: can't find ANY groups or just the specific groups, if there were dns/firewall issues you wouldn't be able to establish the trust successfully in the first place.

Comment: i cant see any group but i will check the ports cause i think this is the issiu and i will update

Comment: i cant find any group  i see the domain i clikc on in when i procced to search for the group i want it seems like i can find anything and form the other domain i try to give right